# SOQL query is not working for multiple status check in Apex

Tags: apex, soql, salesforcedx

I wrote below query for single status check, it is working but not for multiple status checks, it is throwing errors.

```
String draft = 'Draft';
String cancel = 'Cancelled';
String cmpnQuery = 'SELECT ID,Name,FROM Campaign where status!=:draft'; //working without issues

 String campQuery = 'SELECT ID,Name FROM Campaign where status NOT IN (draft,cancel)'; // not working

for(Campaign cmpn:Database.Query(cmpnQuery )){
//TO- DO
}
```

Comment: What error(s) are you getting? Please [edit] your question to include them. It could be that you simply need to add some (escaped) quotes around your target status values in the second query string.

Comment: draft,cancel are string values so use a list and bind that here in the same way you did in last query `Set<String> discardStatuses = new Set<String>{'draft', 'cancel'}` and use it like `'SELECT ID,Name FROM Campaign where status NOT IN :discardStatuses`

Answer (score 4):

You should make a `Set<String>` and add the status to it. Like this

```
Set<String> stringSet = new Set<String>{'draft','cancel'};
```

Then you can update the query to:

```
String campQuery = 'SELECT ID,Name FROM Campaign where status NOT IN: stringSet';
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [Quoted String Escape Sequences](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_quotedstringescapes.htm)  character

```
Database.query('SELECT ID,Name FROM Campaign where status NOT IN (\'draft\',\'cancel\')')
```

Answer (score 0):

Sarvesh and Zach are good anwsers, you can also achieve the same result with the next query.

```
SELECT Id, Name
FROM Campaign
WHERE Status != 'draft'
AND Status != 'cancel'
```